# Flush NSStream without it adding newline characters

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstream

I have a problem with flushing the output stream of my socket client application for iOS.

I need to flush the stream without adding a `\r\n` or `\n`. The server doesn't accept additional bytes in the sent telegram.

Is there any way to flush without adding any characters to the sent data?

```
- (void)openUsingPort: (int)param_port andIp: (NSString*)param_ip
{
     CFReadStreamRef readStream;
     CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

     CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)param_ip, param_port,&readStream, &writeStream);

     inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
     outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

     [inputStream setDelegate:self];
     [outputStream setDelegate:self];


     [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
     [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

     [inputStream open];
     [outputStream open];
}


-(void) sendData:(NMPCommand*) command
{
     NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] init];

     uint8_t buffer[command.infoSize+4];

     buffer[0] = command.cmd;

     buffer[1] = 1;

     buffer[2] = (command.infoSize>>8)&0xFF;
     buffer[3] = command.infoSize&0xFF;

     memcpy(buffer+4, command.rcv_info, command.infoSize);


     [outputStream write:(const uint8_t*)buffer maxLength:(command.infoSize+4)];    


     for(int i = 0;i<command.infoSize+4;i++)
     {
         output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 0x%x", output, buffer[i]];
     }
     NSLog(@"sent data:%@",output);

}
```

Comment: What type of stream "object" are you using?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I inserted the code to answer your question